# How do I migrate my Netbeans themes to other computers?

Tags: ide, netbeans, migration, themes, colors

Short of copying the entire .netbeans directory is there any way to transfer custom Netbeans color schemes to other computers? I am using the latest (6.5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color settings are stored under config/Editors/ in the user directory, so you only need to transfer that portion of the userdir (which should be tiny; most of the bulk of the userdir is taken up in var/ where the code indices etc. live).

-- Tor

Comment: Thanks Tor, love the podcast. I'd love to see some kind of export theme option in the UI. The theme options are so nice in netbeans, it seems a shame to not have this feature.